# Codeigniter form_open specify id

Tags: forms, codeigniter

How can I write the form ID in the form_open function in CodeIgniter? (I need to use the ID for the CSS).
For example, this is simple HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="my_form">
```

I am trying the following code, but it does not work:

```
<?php echo form_open('my_form'); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should research more into de user guide next time.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
$attributes = array('id' => 'myform');
echo form_open('email/send', $attributes);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
echo form_open('controller/method',array('id'=>$id,'method'=>'post'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo form_open('controller/method',array('id'=>$id,'method'=>'post'))
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanations to your code. While it may be self-explanatory to you, other people could very much benefit from some added explaination as to *why* and *how* your code solves the question problem.

Answer (score 0):

like in the doc

```
echo form_open('email/send', 'class="email" id="myform"');
```