# $.post with data returns a HTTP 500 error

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a project with the framework CodeIgniter. I use jQuery 1.7.1 and i want to implement a ajax call with data to add a post message.

The strange thing is that the function works and returns the alert message without the extra data. But the function with the data returns a HTML 500 error (in console from chrome).

The requested page is nothing more then a php script echoing 'It works!'.

Code that works:

```
$.post("/ajax/add_post_to_profile",
            function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
$.post("/ajax/add_post_to_profile", { msg: "My test msg!"},
            function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

### UPDATE:

Here the codeigniter controller that handles the requested page:

```
class PostController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addPostToProfile() {     
        echo 'It works!!!';
    }
}
```

### Update 2:

I have tested the function with a new file request placed in the root of the app. And then it works like a charm.

It looks like the CodeIgniter controller is blocking the POST request or something..

### Update 3:

I found out that it is the CSRF security of CodeIgniter. It works when I turn it off.
I searched the internet for a solution to keep the CSRF, but the code that I found doesn't work :(.

```
<script>
    $('#ajax_test').click(function() {
        $.post("/ajax/add_post_to_profile", { msg: "My test msg!", csrf_token_name: "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"},
            function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1) How does your code actually render in the browser, and 2) have you checked your webserver logs to try to find an explanation of the server error?

Comment: what you have inside this /ajax/add_post_to_profile ?

Comment: 1) The requested page renders correct if you mean that. 2) The error log doesn't show any errors, the access log shows the 500 error.

Comment: @RicardoArruda I updated the question with the controller code.

Comment: What is the content returned from the Ajax call (you can find this in the developer tools of Chrome)? Often a 500 error will return a description of the error in the response.

Comment: @minboost The error in the console: POST http://server.local/ajax/add_post_to_profile 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Are you gzipping your data? check app/config/config.php file.

Comment: @Chumillas No i'm not. But I have the CSRF security on, and that what's creating the error.

Comment: -1 for not providing critical information on how you actually call the Class and method

Comment: @ajreal Are you for real? Really no critical info. Plus you could ask for it instead of down voting..

Comment: check yourself ... http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8523391/revisions compare v1 and v6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick update with the vars in place, it works just tried it, thank you very much ;)

```
<script>

   var csrf_token_name = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";
   var csrf_hash = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";

    $('#ajax_test').click(function() {
        $.post("/ajax/add_post_to_profile", { msg: "My test msg!", csrf_token_name:csrf_hash},
            function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now the function works fine with the CSRF enabled! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can achieve the same, in a better way, with my answer.

Comment: @Chumillas:Can you show me the syntax for form tag? I have the same problem trying to solve it.

Comment: @ram <form id="theForm"> If you want to use CI syntax follow this url [Codeigniter form_open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249834/codeigniter-form-open/6249859#6249859)

Answer (score 0):

check your `site_url` or `add_post_to_profile` file there must be something wrong . otherwise there is nothing wrong with the jquery function

Comment: I already tried to add the site_url helper function, but it just gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your form data if you use CSRF security on!

```
$('#ajax_test').click(function() {
    ...
    data: jQuery('#theForm').serialize(),
    ...
```

Comment: Why do I have to do that? If I understand the info from jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) correctly, then it only creates a string with all the elements of the form (field1=val1&field2=val2 etc.)

Comment: Because Codeigniter adds an input hidden in your forms that you should pass to get it working.

Comment: I already fixed that with adding the token name as a post field with the token hash.